# Artisan commands connect to DB, but Laravel app gives "access denied"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, homestead

I've configured Homestead on Windows 7, but there's a strange problem.

Even though I can **successfully** migrate, seed and use tinker to access data in my database, witch means there's no problem in connecting to DB from artisan commands. On the other side, When I open the App from web browser. I get this Error:

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 119:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I let Homestead uses PHP version that was already installed within xampp folder, and Also I've created the database from phpmyadmin.

Here's my .env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:1FkydoMHj30+3lRA4+mes1Gw7/AMSZ5JCIqx3Xmecgc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myestore
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123
```

**UPDATE:**

I've returned the .env file to the default configs and started executing commands from VM rather than before. Everything is okay now.

Comment: Are you execute artisan commands from the local machine of from the homesteam, e.g. from the virtual machine by ssh'ing there first?

Comment: Thank you. I've discovered that I'm executing commands from host machine after 14 hours!! sorry I didn't have good internet connection to update my question.